# Ordenar de mayor a menor - PHP

Tags: php

Estoy creando una sección para servidores patrocinados y me gustaría crear lo siguiente:
Una tabla, que muestre los servidores patrocinados, los cuales deben ser clasificados de mayor a menor en una tabla. Se clasificarán dependiendo de la cantidad de votos que tiene cada uno, y el primero que aparezca en la tabla debe tener la etiqueta `<tr class="success">`, mientras que los demas deben tener la etiqueta `<tr>`.

El archivo *servidores-patrocinados.json* almacena 3 servidores patrocinados en formato JSON.
El archivo *todos-los-servidores.json* contiene muchos más servidores incluyendo los servidores patrocinados, y por cada uno hay una clave `VOTOS` que contiene un número entero de la cantidad de votos del servidor. Los servidores patrocinados deben organizarse de mayor a menor **gracias a la cantidad de votos de cada uno**.

He intentado utilizando el siguiente código PHP:

```
<?php foreach(json_decode(file_get_contents('servidores-patrocinados.json')) as $servidor_patrocinado) {
if(!max((arsort(json_decode(file_get_contents('todos-los-servidores.json')))['VOTOS'] == $servidor_patrocinado)) continue; //Continuar al siguiente foreach, el primero necesita ser el con más votos
}
?>
```

Y no me ha funcionado.

## Estructura de archivos

*servidores-patrocinados.json*:

```
[
    {
        "NAME": "Aphmau Craft",
        "MCPE_LIST": "minecraftpocket-servers.com",
        "ALIAS": "Aphmau"
    },
    {
        "NAME": "CCPvP",
        "MCPE_LIST": "minecraftpocket-servers.com",
        "ALIAS": "Vote"
    },
    {
        "NAME": "OPMCPE",
        "MCPE_LIST": "minecraftpocket-servers.com",
        "ALIAS": "r8i5"
    }
]
```

*todos-los-servidores.json*:
(Son muchos más):

```
[
    {
        "MCPE_LIST": "minecraftpocket-servers.com",
        "URL": "https:\/\/minecraftpocket-servers.com\/server\/62849\/vote\/",
        "PREMIUM": false,
        "ALIAS": "5hv7",
        "VOTES": 6,
        "SERVER_NAME": "DateCraftRP",
        "PASSWORD": "$2y$10$UVFMjTy4EtlkN3NFpFhRHOis..EKk5mg5GfpCkcDzO5EERh0kQ3jq"
    },
    {
        "MCPE_LIST": "minecraftpocket-servers.com",
        "URL": "https:\/\/minecraftpocket-servers.com\/server\/64455\/",
        "PREMIUM": false,
        "ALIAS": "Aphmau",
        "VOTES": 284,
        "SERVER_NAME": "Aphmau Craft!",
        "PASSWORD": "$2y$10$xsjwMaheRlfhx.5MXOdFPOJLmEIPlCi12ONWQIXrjxtVVlkW5LYRC"
    },
    {
        "MCPE_LIST": "minecraftpocket-servers.com",
        "URL": "https:\/\/minecraftpocket-servers.com\/server\/49063",
        "PREMIUM": false,
        "ALIAS": "Ashcraft",
        "VOTES": 0,
        "SERVER_NAME": "AshcraftPE",
        "PASSWORD": "$2y$10$1K2o79HQ52dDs\/KxZ1kH0.ogTWyRZvBa02qg5DgqNlfZmfQhMGr8m"
    }
]
```

Por cierto, la `ALIAS` es utilizada para diferenciar un servidor de otro.

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] la pregunta con el contenido/estructura de los archivos `.json`?

Comment: @MatiasOlivera Dame 1 minuto, actualizo mi publicación. Actualizado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**¿Cómo crear la tabla con los servidores patrocinadores ordenados según la cantidad votos de forma ascendente?**

Primero vamos a usar función [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php) para obtener el contenido del archivo `json` y almacenar la cadena en la variable `$jsonP`.

```
$jsonP = file_get_contents('servidores-patrocinados.json');
$jsonS = file_get_contents('todos-los-servidores.json');
```

Después mediante la función [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) se decodifica la cadena `JSON` y se la convierte a una variable de `PHP`.

```
$patrocinados = json_decode($jsonP, true);
$servidores = json_decode($jsonS, true);
```

Recorremos el arreglo `$patrocinados`, en cada iteración se recorre el arreglo `$servidores` para buscar si existen dos servidores con el mismo alias, en caso de que así sea se añade el elemento del arreglo `$servidores` (es el que tiene los votos) al arreglo `$servers`.

```
foreach ($patrocinados as $patrocinado) {
    foreach ($servidores as $servidor) {
        if ($servidor["ALIAS"] == $patrocinado["ALIAS"]) {
            $servers[] = $servidor;
        }
    }
}
```

Como ya tenemos la variable `$servers` que contiene un arreglo bidimensional con los servidores patrocinados y los votos de cada uno de ellos, lo que nos queda hacer es ordenarla usando la función [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.usort.php) que recibe dos parámetros, el primer parámetro es un arreglo y el segundo es una función que define cómo se debe ordenar el arreglo. La función compara si los votos (`$a["VOTES"]`) de un elemento es menor que los de otro (`$b["VOTES"]`), si la condición se cumple devuelve `1` sino devuelve `-1`.

*Esta sintaxis `condición ? verdadero : falso` es del operador ternario, se puede hacer lo mismo mediante la sentencia de control `if`, es decir, `if (condicion) {verdadero} else {falso}`.*

```
usort($servers, function($a, $b) {
    return $a["VOTES"] < $b["VOTES"] ? 1 : -1;
});
?>
```

En este momento el arreglo se encuentra ordenado y solamente nos queda recorrer el mismo para agregar las filas (`<tr>`) a la tabla (`<table>`).

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Votos</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="servidores">
        <?php foreach ($servers as $servidor) { ?>
            <!-- Se podría agregar un if que compruebe si es la primera fila 
            (es decir, si el indice es igual a 0) para colocar la clase "success", 
            pero no es muy elegante -->
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $servidor["SERVER_NAME"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $servidor["VOTES"] ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**¿Cómo agregar la clase `success` a la primera fila de la tabla?**

Primero hay que seleccionar el primer hijo (`<tr>`) del `<tbody>` mediante la propiedad `firstChildElement`.

```
var primeraFila = document.getElementById('servidores').firstElementChild;
```

Después se le añade la clase `success` modificando la propiedad `classList`.

```
primeraFila.classList.add('success');
```

**Código completo**

```
<?php

$jsonP = file_get_contents('servidores-patrocinados.json');
$patrocinados = json_decode($jsonP, true);

$jsonS = file_get_contents('todos-los-servidores.json');
$servidores = json_decode($jsonS, true);

foreach ($patrocinados as $patrocinado) {
    foreach ($servidores as $servidor) {
        if ($servidor["ALIAS"] == $patrocinado["ALIAS"]) {
            $servers[] = $servidor;
        }
    }
}

usort($servers, function($a, $b) {
    return $a["VOTES"] < $b["VOTES"] ? 1 : -1;
});
?>
```

```js
var primeraFila = document.getElementById('servidores').firstElementChild;
primeraFila.classList.add('success');
```

```css
.success {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Votos</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="servidores">
        <?php foreach ($servers as $servidor) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $servidor["SERVER_NAME"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $servidor["VOTES"] ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Gracias, pero eso ordenaría todos los servidores. Solo quiero ordenar los servidores patrocinados. El *todos-los-servidores.json* debiese abrirse para buscar la cantidad de votos, utilizando como referencia las aliases de cada uno de los servidores de *servidores-patrocinados.json*.

Comment: funciona perfecto, pero revisa mi comentario superior

Comment: @JorgeSalas Sí, cuando encuentre como hacerlo edito la respuesta.

Comment: @JorgeSalas Listo, edite la respuesta!

Comment: Gracias, pero te molestaria pedirte ayuda con una tabla dentro de un bootstrap modal?

Comment: @JorgeSalas Te sugiero que leas [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) para entender cómo funciona el sitio. Si tenes otras dudas, solo tenes que crear nuevas preguntas.